# How to multiply a vector and matrix when the matrix includes a translation?

Tags: rotations, projective-geometry, matrix-equations

What is the proper way to right multiply an $N$ x $N$ matrix $H$ by an $N$ x $1$ vector $\mathbf{v}$, if $H$ includes a translation vector?

For example, say

$$H=R-\mathbf{tn}^T$$

where $R$ is a conventional rotation matrix, $\mathbf{t}$ is a translation vector and $\mathbf{n}^T$ is the transpose of the normal vector to a plane.  And I want to figure out $\mathbf{v'}$:

$$\mathbf{v'}=H\mathbf{v}$$

The rotation part of the equation is easy (say $N=2$ and $\mathbf{v}=(x,y)$):

$$R\mathbf{v}=\begin{bmatrix}x_r\\y_r\end{bmatrix} =\begin{bmatrix}\cos{\theta} & -\sin{\theta}\\\sin{\theta} & \cos{\theta}\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}x\\y\end{bmatrix}$$

$$\begin{matrix}x_r=x\cos{\theta}-y\sin{\theta} \\y_r=x\sin{\theta}+y\cos{\theta}\end{matrix}$$

But now I'm not sure what to do with the translation part.

$$\mathbf{tn}^T\mathbf{v}=?$$

Help is appreciated.  The matrix $H$ in this question is based on the [homography matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homography_%28computer_vision%29).

Comment: $\mathbf{tn}^T$ should itself be a matrix, being the product of a vector with a transposed vector (in that order). So you can go on with the same kind of multiplication.

Comment: Yes. the (i,j) elements of matrix $\mathbf{tn}^T$ is $t_i n_j$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$\mathbf{v'}=H\mathbf{v}=(R-\mathbf{tn}^T)\mathbf{v}=R\mathbf{v}-\mathbf{t}(\mathbf{n\cdot v})$$

where $\mathbf{n\cdot v}$ is a scalar.